# setState and JSX props should not use arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have read similar questions here

[Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind)

[JSX props should not use .bind() - how to avoid using bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121820/jsx-props-should-not-use-bind-how-to-avoid-using-bind)

[No .bind() or Arrow Functions in JSX Props making no sense to me when I need to pass arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217293/no-bind-or-arrow-functions-in-jsx-props-making-no-sense-to-me-when-i-need-to)

And I understand how using an arrow function causes the function to be recreated on each render and effects performance. However I still don't fully understand how to resolve this issue in React Native, specifically when using setState.

For example, if I have a TextInput that updates a value held in the component state in the onChangeText function, how do I avoid using an arrow function?

```
<TextInput
  value={this.state.text}
  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
  />
```

Must I create a handler for each property in the state that I want to update? For example, if I have two TextInput fields Email and Password, would that need to be handled like this?

```
  updateEmail = email => {
    this.setState({ email })
  }

  updatePassword = password => {
    this.setState({ password })
  }

  render() {
  ...
  <TextInput
      value={this.state.email}
      onChangeText={this.updateEmail}
      />
  <TextInput
      value={this.state.password}
      onChangeText={this.updatePassword}
      />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set id or name of an element same with the name of a state variable. So you can create one function and pass it to all inputs like:

```
onFieldChange = (e) => {
    const key = e.target.id
    const value = e.target.value
    this.setState({[key]:value})
}
```

Comment: I tried setting id and name on TextInput like `TextInput id="customer" name="customer" onChange={this.onFieldChange} />` but onFieldChange e.target.id and e.target.value are undefined. How are you accomplishing this?

Comment: Did you bind your function? More info on that here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Comment: You don't have to bind when using an arrow function I thought?

Comment: That's binding as well. I just asked to check. So your e.target is completely undefined?

Comment: Correct. I can call e.nativeEvent, but that does not contain id or name when I set them on the element.

Comment: Can you pass name as parameter like onFieldChange = (name, e) => ?

Comment: I just found this function in a forum and it seems to be working but it is not similar to your solution or others I have found on SO  `handleTextChange = fieldName => {
    return event => {
      this.setState({
        [fieldName]: event.nativeEvent.text
      })
    }
  }`

Comment: The above function works so I will use it, although I am confused why I cannot use your method because when searching SO I have found others using your method also

Comment: If that worked what I wrote just above should have also worked. Interesting. Try to mess up with the code maybe you'll figure it out.

Comment: Ah I found that example as well. There you send field name explicitly as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

### Generic way

Create your own TextInput component that takes an `id` prop and passes it as a second parameter when calling the handler. This is the generic way to handle it:

```
class MyTextInput extends Component {

    handleTextChange = text => {
        const {id, onTextChange} = this.props;
        return onTextChange && onTextChange(text, id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput {...this.props} onTextChange={this.handleTextChange}
        );
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
class App extends Component {

    handleTextChange = (text, id) => this.setState({[id]: text});

    render() {
        const {email, password} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <MyTextInput
                    id="email"
                    value={email} 
                    onTextChange={this.handleTextChange}
                />
                <MyTextInput
                    id="password" 
                    value={password}
                    onTextChange={this.handleTextChange}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As it does not use arrow functions it avoids performance penalties if you have a large amount of components. But note that the penalty is marginal for only a few components and not worth the effort in most of the cases. Just make sure you do not forward the handler that is an arrow function multiple levels deep.

### Easy way for react-native `TextInput`

Use the `onChange` handler which gets the `event` instead of only the text. The event also contains the `name` of the input if one way provied to it:

```
class App extends Component {

    handleChange = event => {
        const {name, value} = event.nativeEvent;
        this.setState({[name]: value});
    }

    render() {
        const {email, password} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <MyTextInput
                    name="email"
                    value={email} 
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <MyTextInput
                    name="password" 
                    value={password}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this method (the easy way for react-native). I have onChange in my TextInput being handled by a method like your example. But I can't get name or value from event.nativeEvent. I only see `{ eventCount: 1, target: 277, text: (whatever I have typed) }`. Any ideas?